# What is the fastest way of animating multiple sprites under html5?

Tags: performance, html, animation, canvas

I'm trying to animate 50 or so sprites at the same time, using a setInterval of 30ms.

What gives bettter performance?
Using canvas? Or using -webkit-transform and divs? Does anyone have any tips on making animations for html5?

Comment: well... `while(true){}` should do the trick. (joke)

Comment: I found this quora answer to a similar question quite useful: [http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-get-faster-frame-rates-with-HTML5-Canvas/answer/Miller-Medeiros](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-get-faster-frame-rates-with-HTML5-Canvas/answer/Miller-Medeiros)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that Canvas should give better performance.

This post from Facebook engineering should also be helpful in your understanding of Canvas speeds:

http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/html5-games-01-speedy-sprites/491691753919

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript and HTML5 canvas will give less headache than `-webkit-transform` and divs when you need to make changes to the animation.

I personally recommend HTML5 canvas and Javascript for compatibility (for now), since `-webkit-transform` is only available on Webkit browsers.

Sticking to the rule that human eyes cannot see frame changes beyond the speed of 20 frames per second (FPS), A `setInterval()` timer of 0.05s (aka 50ms) would probably be the best.

I follow how XNA game framework works, so I usually have 2 `setInterval()` calls, 1 to do the logic updates, and the other to draw the canvas.

Comment: why one to update position and another to draw canvas? any particular reason?

Comment: it's mainly to prevent slow frame speed. For example, it may take a very long time to do the logic updates, and if you have to calculate those logic updates each time you draw, the FPS becomes very low as you need more time to draw.

Comment: There is little point in doing separate update/render intervals unless you are updating them at a different rate. You will not get any performance benefit out of splitting them up if they are running at the same frequency.